# jQuery read XML and save for data for access in another plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 2 large XML files:

1. Car data (id, name, image, etc).
2. Deals (car_id, miles, speed, etc)

At the moment I firstly read the Car XML using jQuery AJAX and generate the relevant HTML.

The problem is that next I need to read in the Tariff XML which has the car_id, although I would like to get the car image. How can I go about saving the car_id and image in temporary memory without reading the XML file again to find the image?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: carXmlPath,
    dataType: "xml",
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(xml){
        carCarousel.html("");
        $(xml).find("car").each(function(index, value){
            var tis = $(this), first = '';
            if(index == 0) first = ' class="selected"';
            carCarousel.append('<li'+first+' data-id="'+tis.find("id").text()+'">' + tis.find("name").text() + tis.find("thumbnail").text() + '</li>');
        }); 
        carCarousel.removeClass("loading");
    }           
});
```

I know this should all be implemented on the server but that is not an option here, it has to be done in JS.

Comment: Why can't you make a variable and put the car id into it?

Comment: Wont this overwrite the variable? The reading of both XML files are within 2 different plugins

Comment: You will have to define two global variables (i.e. outside of any function), e.g. `var cars, deals;`, to store you ajax data permanently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're creating document fragments to attach to the DOM, then I would use data islands.

E.g. data-car-img and data-car-id.

Comment: Do you mean save it as physical attributes to the HTML element? or using the jQuery.data()

Comment: It saves as actual attributes.